Access denied trying to create remote squeduled task
I am trying to add a task remotely to a computer on the same domain as mine.
schtasks /create /sc DAILY /tn remotask /tr C:\ /s <<othercomputerIP>>
It gives me: ACCESS DENIED.
Could this be lack of permissions? Because i tried:
schtasks /create /sc DAILY /tn remotask /tr C:\ /s <<othercomputerIP>> /ru [<<domain>>]<<username>> /rp <<password>>
and still gave me the same error.
What should I be checking before trying to add the task?
fyi: I am running this on a Admin cmd.
